# Count number of rows in each day grouped by another field

Tags: mysql, sql

For the purpose of drawing an activity chart, how can we count number of rows for each type (distinct field value) in each day?

Consider a table with a date field and a field for each type:

```
CREATE TABLE TableName
    (`PK` int, `type` varchar(1), `timestamp` datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO TableName
    (`PK`, `type`, `timestamp`)
VALUES
    (11, 'Q', '2013-01-04 22:23:56'),
    (7, 'A', '2013-01-03 22:23:41'),
    (8, 'C', '2013-01-04 22:23:42'),
    (10, 'Q', '2013-01-05 22:23:56'),
    (5, 'C', '2013-01-03 22:23:25'),
    (12, 'Q', '2013-01-05 22:23:57'),
    (6, 'Q', '2013-01-07 22:23:40'),
    (4, 'Q', '2013-01-02 22:23:23'),
    (9, 'A', '2013-01-05 22:23:55'),
    (1, 'A', '2013-01-08 21:29:38'),
    (2, 'Q', '2013-01-02 21:31:59'),
    (3, 'C', '2013-01-04 21:32:22')
;
```

For example output can be (last field is the count of rows with that type and in that day):

```
'Q', 2013-01-04, 1
'C', 2013-01-04, 2
'A', 2013-01-03, 1
'C', 2013-01-03, 2
and so on...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select `type`, date(`timestamp`) as the_date, count(*) as counter
from MyTable
group by `type`, date(`timestamp`)
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need a `group by`.

```
select `type`, date(`timestamp`), count(*)
from tableName
group by `type`, date(`timestamp`)
```